# how to upgrade a jailbroken ipad3 (ios5.1.1) to ios 6.x and jailbreak it again?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ipad

I have a jail broken ipad3 with IOS 5.1.1
and I want to upgrade it to a newer version of IOS.
I have the following Problems:

1. which version should i upgrade to and how
2. can i keep my programs, pictures, movies, books, etc... after upgrade and jailbreak
3. i googled about 2 days and most people said that current version of available upgrade can not be jailbroken and we should wait untill 7, is it true? can we now upgrade to pilot IOS7?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can't unless you have SHSH blobs and valid APTickets (which you most likely don't because of a bug in Cydia's signing servers).

Comment: thanks @AndrewLarsson, can you explain it abit more in an answer for me to understand and accept?